# using random ports with iperf/iperf3

Tags: iperf

I am using  Iperf/iperf3 -c remotehost which is

> iPerf3 is a tool for active measurements of the maximum achievable bandwidth on IP networks. It supports tuning of various parameters related to timing, buffers and protocols (TCP, UDP, SCTP with IPv4 and IPv6).

My  question is how to use random port with a specific range (5300-5400) while using `Iperf/iperf3 -c remotehost`

Answer (score 3):

iperf3 is a client-server tool, and requires predeterminated port on “server” side. The default is 5201. You can specify the port with “-p” argument. You cannot use the range of ports. But if need to run multithreading network test, you can run simultaneously multiple iperf processes with different ports, for example:

```
iperf3 -s -p 5301
iperf3 -s -p 5302
iperf3 -s -p 5303
 …
```

The same applies to "client" side.